# Magento 2.3.3 Mini Cart Disable Checkout Button When A Product = $0.00

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I want to disable the checkout button from the mini cart when an (or any) item is added that has **$0.00** as a price.

I have copied the `minicart.phtml` file from: `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart` and added it to my theme. I am confused because the calls look like they are in Javascript and PHP. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would override **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js** in my theme or module and check there if any of the items is got a 0$ price to use jquery to disable/enable the button